# Get the values of a particular object from a C# List of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I'm working in a WPF window in which I have a class which is fetching data from the database using dbset.
Below is the view model class of data.

```
public class CriteriaSheetVM
    {
        public string ReviewNumber { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    }
```

and i'm creating a list of above class objects:

```
List<CriteriaSheetVM> criteriaSheet;
```

My query is to get all the values stored in the **EmployeeLastName** from the above List and to compare each value with the value in the TextBox `txtEmpLastName` and return TRUE when found else FALSE.

**UPDATE:**

I have used below code for it.

```
criteriaSheet.ForEach(a =>
                {
                    if (a.EmployeeLastName == txtEmpLastName.Text)
                    {
                       bool flag = 1;
                    }
                });
```

and it was not working

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want multiple result:

```
var results = criteriaSheet.Where(cs=>cs.EmployeeLastName ==txtEmpLastName.Text);
```

If you want to one result:

```
var result = criteriaSheet.FirstOrDefault(cs=>cs.EmployeeLastName ==txtEmpLastName.Text);
```